# how to let solr suggester return suggestions with score

Tags: solr, autosuggest

I'm using Apache SOLR 4.1 and I am using the Suggester component. However, I cannot figure out how to have it also output the score/frequency per suggestion. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks,

Ygor

Comment: why not use the http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SpellCheckComponent?